# Uninitialized constant Google::Cloud raised by Google::Cloud::Translate.new in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api

I have a GoogleTranslate service that translates text in my app. The feature works on localhost but in production it raises

> uninitialized constant Google::Cloud in my app/helpers/google_translations_helper.rb:4:in `initialize'...

Here is the `Gemfile` related part :

```
# use of google API
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.11', :require  => 
'google/apis/analyticsreporting_v4'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem "google-cloud-translate"
```

And here is the `helper/service` initializer:

```
module GoogleTranslationsHelper
 class GoogleTranslate
  def initialize
    @translation_service = Google::Cloud::Translate.new
  end

  def translate(text)
    @translation_service.translate text.to_s, from: "fr", to: "en"
  end
 end
end
```

I wonder if I'm not missing something about gem version or something like that..

Does someone had the problem already?

Comment: You might try `@translation_service = ::Google::Cloud::Translate.new` to force constant lookup in the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running Rails. Make sure you include:

```
require "google/cloud/translate"
```

somewhere reasonable, either at the top of the file that creates the client object (`app/helpers/google_translations_helper.rb` in your case), or in a global initialization file such as `config/application.rb`. (The google-cloud-translate library, like most libraries, needs you to require it before you can use it. See the snippets in the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-translate/latest/index.html) for examples.)

It's not completely clear to me why this is working differently between your development and production environments, but there are usually a lot of differences in the initialization procedure between the two environments so it's not too surprising. Just make sure you're in the habit of requiring any library before using it.

As a side note, I would also recommend updating your Gemfile to call for more recent versions of the Google client libraries. Or at least make sure you've done a recent `bundle update`. As of this writing, google-api-client 0.11 is more than 2 years old; the newest is 0.30.8. And google-cloud-translate is at 1.3.0. It is always possible there are issues if you're on old versions.